# Как закрыть текущую вкладку браузера с помощью js?

Tags: jquery, javascript

Есть небольшая задачка - делаю HTML кнопку, как при нажатии на эту кнопку закрыть текущую вкладку браузера? И возможно ли такое сделать?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2076299/how-to-close-current-tab-in-a-browser-window

Answer (score 2):

методом `close();`

напиши `window.close();` и все